# Return unconnected islands of nodes in a network with Networkx

Tags: python, networkx, isolation

I am using NetworkX for analyzing a network G of transport connections. After visualizing it I saw that there are some "islands" of nodes that do not have any connections to the network. Those islands mostly consist of 2 to 5 nodes. Since the network is really big I am looking for a command that returns each of those islands, preferrably in a data structure that indicates the names of the nodes.  The `isolates(G)` command only returns nodes of degree zero, but I am interested in the islands. Is there a command for that?

Comment: Quick question - is the graph directed?  This affects the answer a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look into the [`connected_components`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.connected_components) function

```
# Create three separate graphs and then compose them together.
import networkx as nx
G = nx.complete_graph(8)
G2 = nx.complete_graph(range(13, 15))
G3 = nx.complete_graph(range(16, 19))

G = nx.compose_all([G, G2, G3])
nx.draw(G)
```

[image: Graphs]

Using `connected_components()`:

```
list(nx.connected_components(G))
```

```
[{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {13, 14}, {16, 17, 18}]
```

```
threshold = 6
[c for c in nx.connected_components(G) if len(c) < threshold]
```

```
[{13, 14}, {16, 17, 18}]
```

You can also check out [connected_components_subgraph](https://networkx.org/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.connected.connected_component_subgraphs.html)